# Late binding to avoid "User defined type not defined" error

Tags: vba, ms-word, domdocument, msxml

In Word 2010 macro VBA, i set

```
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
```

to get xml type Word.officeUI file.

But when i call the sub that handling Word.officeUI file

```
user defined type not defined
```

error rised.

I don't want to add any necessary .dll or another source from TOOLS > REFERENCES
I need to add any thing in run time (first opening of Word).
Here is my actual code in use at below,

```
' bu özel sub sadece onLoad event'ına karşılık gelen ve belge ilk defa yüklendiğinde çalışan özel bir sub
Private Sub Document_Open()
Application.ActiveDocument.VBProject.References.AddFromFile ("C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll")
Call officeUI_duzelt
End Sub

Function yeniDosyaAdiVer()
yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri = Split(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".")
yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleriSayisi = UBound(yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri)
    For xcv = 0 To (yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleriSayisi - 1)
        sonDosyaAdi = sonDosyaAdi & yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri(xcv) & "."
        yeniDosyaAdiVer = sonDosyaAdi
    Next
End Function


Sub TITCK2pdf()
    With ActiveDocument
    sondurum = Replace(yeniDosyaAdiVer(), (.Path & "\"), "")
    'MsgBox (sondurum)
    sonPDFAdi = .Path & "\titck-imza-" & sondurum & "pdf"
    'MsgBox (.FullName & Chr(13) & sonPDFAdi)

      .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=sonPDFAdi, _
      ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
      OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
      Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
      CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
      BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    End With
End Sub

Sub TITCK_ic2pdf()
    With ActiveDocument
    sondurum = Replace(yeniDosyaAdiVer(), (.Path & "\"), "")
    'MsgBox (sondurum)
    sonPDFAdi = .Path & "\titck-imza-ic-" & sondurum & "pdf"
    'MsgBox (.FullName & Chr(13) & sonPDFAdi)

      .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=sonPDFAdi, _
      ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
      OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
      Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
      CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
      BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    End With
End Sub

Sub officeUI_duzelt()
' // OfficeUI dosyasının yolu alınıyor
OfficeUI_yolu = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\Word.officeUI"

' // OfficeUI dosyası (xml formatında) ele alınıyor
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
objXML.Load (OfficeUI_yolu)

'// OfficeUI içindeki node bilgileri ele alınıyor
Set dugmelerinAnaci = objXML.getElementsByTagName("mso:sharedControls")(0)


'// Daha önce değişiklik yapılmış mı  kontrol amaçlı girdi bakılıyor
Set modifikasyon = objXML.getElementsByTagName("modifikasyon")

'// Modifikasyon yapıldıysa sub'dan çıkılıyor
'MsgBox (modifikasyon.Length)
If modifikasyon.Length > 0 Then
Exit Sub
End If
'/////////////////////////////////////// SUB çıkış şartı var üstte

' // Her durumda modifikasyon yapılacak (modifikasyon nodu eklenecek (mso:sharedControls ana nodunun altına ekleniyor)
Set mdf = objXML.createElement("modifikasyon")
dugmelerinAnaci.appendChild mdf




'// mso:button node'larına ait xml içerikleri gösteriliyor
'Set yeniDegerler = objXML.getElementsByTagName("mso:button")
'For yD = 0 To (yeniDegerler.Length - 1)
'MsgBox (yeniDegerler(yD).XML)
'Next



' Element ekleniyor ve o elemente attribute'lar ekleniyor
Set yNesne = elementYaratVeEkle("mso:button", dugmelerinAnaci, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("idQ", "x1:TITCK_ic2pdf_1", yNesne, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("visible", "true", yNesne, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("label", "İç yazışma PDF yapıcısı", yNesne, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("imageMso", "AppointmentColor3", yNesne, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("onAction", "TITCK_ic2pdf", yNesne, objXML)

Set yNesne = elementYaratVeEkle("mso:button", dugmelerinAnaci, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("idQ", "x1:TITCK2pdf_1", yNesne, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("visible", "true", yNesne, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("label", "Dış yazışma PDF yapıcısı", yNesne, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("imageMso", "AppointmentColor1", yNesne, objXML)
    yAttribute = attributeYaratVeEkle("onAction", "TITCKpdf", yNesne, objXML)



've kayıt
objXML.Save (OfficeUI_yolu)
End Sub
Function elementYaratVeEkle(elementAdi, AnacElementNesnesi, hazirXMLNesnesi)
Set objYeniNesne = hazirXMLNesnesi.createElement(elementAdi)
AnacElementNesnesi.appendChild objYeniNesne
Set elementYaratVeEkle = objYeniNesne
End Function
Function attributeYaratVeEkle(attributeAdi, attributeDegeri, AnacElementNesnesi, hazirXMLNesnesi)
Set objXMLattr = hazirXMLNesnesi.createAttribute(attributeAdi)
objXMLattr.NodeValue = attributeDegeri
AnacElementNesnesi.setAttributeNode objXMLattr
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry for the miss-meaning title. There is no early-bounding or prebounding references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to make it late-bound:

```
Dim objXML As Object
Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
```

Now you don't need to set an explicit reference to MSXML.