# Is it possible to insert VBA macros into word 2010 with C# (with an exe)?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word

Is it possible to insert VBA macros into Word 2010 with C# (with an exe)?  I want to deploy a word2010 macro to our co-workers in my office. This my 2rd-3th question around this problem. Add-in or module method has failed. Very difficult to them. I need one-click exe to set a bunch of macros in to normal.dot. 
Thanks

Comment: May be you should ask windows administrators on how to roll out changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a new VBA module, insert your code and run it. I use this, because macro is in some cases faster then C# code (yes, unbelievable, but true; I don't know why). Here is an example:

```
//creating a new VBA module (must be a reference to Microsoft.Vbe.Interop)
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.VBComponent vbaModule = 
     docComp.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(
     Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule); 

//insert VBA macro code
vbaModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(string_with_your_vba_code);

//run the macro
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", 
     BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
     null,
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application,
     new Object[] { "name_of_your_main_sub" });
```

The magic of running macro is described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683/en-us).

Comment: Thank you @Roman Plischke. Here is the code i wrote in VBA (word2010) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323598/late-binding-to-avoid-user-defined-type-not-defined-error